# Catching exceptions and recording them in excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a function as follows:

```
public int CreateMyTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
    Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    return m_taskID;
}
```

What I need to do is :-

1. I must check the function whether an exception has occurred. Any exception can occur basically. We are not bothered about what exception has occurred. We simple need to find whether AN exception HAS occurred or not. Let that exception be anything.
2. If an exception has indeed occurred, I must record a word "FAIL" in row 2, cell 10 of my excel sheet (D:\excel.xls) and add the text related to the exception like "Nullreference exception has occurred" or "divide by zero exception has occurred" or any exception that has occurred. The exact text of the exception must be copied to row 2, cell 11
3. If no exception has occurred, then I must record a word "PASS" in row 2, cell 10 of my excel sheet.

Can someone help me to get started on this ? Am quite new to c#. Could so with some inputs.

Comment: first google and try something and then come with problem.

Comment: Yes, please google "c# excel interop" which will get you started. Also use "catch (Exception ex)" to catch all exceptions.

Comment: When question that immediately springs to mind is can this run more than once and if so what happens when you have multiple exceptions? It obviously depends on your context but have you considered storing the exceptions in a database and retrieving them from there with excel (a pretty simple process needing no real coding).

Comment: @chris multiple exception is not an issue. can u help me with code for just a single exception?

Comment: 'fraid not. I haven't done this kind of thing though following the link Daniel McNulty provided for try/catch (to catch the exception) and google Excel interop as ShellShock suggested then that will put you on the right path. Then you can ask a more specific question about where your problem is rather than just asking for all the code (which isn't really what we do here in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int CreateMyTask()
{
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
            Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            WriteResultInExcel(false, "");
            return m_taskID;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteResultInExcel(true, ex.Message);
        }
}


 private void WriteResultInExcel(bool isExceptionalData, string message)
 {
        Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new ApplicationClass();
        Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\excel.xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        if(isExceptionalData)
        {
            ((Range)worksheet.Cells["2", "J"]).Value2 = "FAIL";
            ((Range)worksheet.Cells["2", "K"]).Value2 = message;
        }
        else
        {
            ((Range)worksheet.Cells["2", "J"]).Value2 = "PASS";
        }
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close(0, 0, 0);
        excelApp.Quit();
 }
```

Make sure to check the existence of your file "D:\excel.xls" and also add the reference to "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel".

Don't miss to add this to your directives section:

**using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;**

Comment: hi i did as u said...it works fine..but there is a small problem..in d excel file, i only see a text "Exception <text>" I want full text of the description to be there..like "Nullreferenceexception was found"  am i missing something???

Comment: Can you put a debug point at 'WriteResultInExcel' function code and let me know what you value you get in the string 'message'?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is two fold. Firstly, wrap a try catch block around the functionality of this method. Whether this is done within the method or around any calls of the CreateMyTask method depends on the wider structure and use of your code. For becoming familiar with the use of try catch refer to this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/catch - In this link, you will replace the writeline's with the method that will write to your Excel sheet. I'd need more context on the way in which you plan to write to your spreadsheet but, as suggested, google ways to read and write from an excel file.

Comment: It will be useful for me if u can help me with the code for the above function. Just catch any exception, if it is a pass, write d word PASS to the excel sheet at the specified position. if it is a fail, write d word FAIL to the excel sheet and write the exception description too.

Comment: It would be useful for me too if I could get someone else to write my code, unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: @user1463269 - it doesn't work like that. I'm not spoon feeding you code. All you have to do is the two things I recommended you do and you've got your solution. Not to mention the fact you'll then know it for any future projects.